# VirtualBox not freeing up Cores from old VMS

Tags: virtualbox

I am attempting to get a virtual machine running with Ubuntu Bionic beaver. The first couple times I started one went well. Very easy to install using the image and I would assign more cores to make it faster. I would also give a bit more ram to the VM. I would use these VM's to test certain things then delete them and reset. I assumed that VirtualBox would delete the usage of disk space, ram, and cores. Yet now when I try to create a virtual machine using the same instance of Bionic Beaver, it says that I haven't allocated enough core (though one should be enough?). Is virtual box not freeing up the hardware it uses? That is what it seems like to me from digging around. Thanks for your help. P.S. The VirtualBox version is 5.2.18. The Ubuntu bionic beaver is 18.04.1 LTS. I am running Windows 10 on the host computer

Comment: Please, can you add versions?

Comment: I've done that thanks, let me know if I need any other version.